# ActiveRecord relationships between HAVE and IS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So I have the following models in my Ruby on Rails setup: **users** and **courses**

The **courses** need to have **content_managers** and those **content_managers** are made up of several individuals in the **users** model.

I'm a newbie, so bear with me.  I was thinking of creating a new model called content_managers that has a user_id and a course_id that links the two tables.  It makes sense to me that courses HAVE content_managers.  However from the users model, it doesn't make sense that users HAVE content_managers.  Some of them ARE content_managers.

From that point of view I believe I'm thinking about it incorrectly and need to set up my ActiveRecord in a different manner from what I'm envisioning.  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no "have" or "are" in ActiveRecord, only "has_many", "has_one" and "belongs_to". With those tools you should be able to do what you want.

An example:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :content_managers
end

class ContentManager < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :content_manager_members
  has_many :users,
    :through => :content_manager_members,
    :source => :user
end

class ContentManagerMember < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course_manager
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :content_manager_members
  has_many :content_managers,
    :through => :content_manager_members
end
```

Be sure to index these correctly and you should be fine, though navigating from User to Course will be slow. You may need to cache some of this in order to find the level of performance you want, but that's a separate issue that will be uncovered during testing.

Whenever implementing something like this, be sure to load it up with a sufficient amount of test data that will represent about 10x the anticipated usage level to know where the ceiling is. Some structures perform very well only at trivial dataset sizes, but melt down when exposed to real-world conditions.

Comment: thanks tadman....especially for the testing advice.  I'm looking at the implementation you outlined and I'm wondering what the purpose of ContentManagerMember is.  Would it be possible to have the ContentManager as (belongs_to :courses, belongs_to :users) that way I just need to define one model?

Comment: Since `belongs_to` requires a singular foreign key field, it is not possible to belong to more than one thing. After all, `belongs_to :user` implies the presence of a `user_id` field. You can't create a  `user_ids` field the same way. If I'm right in my understanding, ContentManager acts as a group of users, so to establish group membership you need the intermediate join model ContentManagerMember to represent the relationship of a User to a ContentManager group.